# C++ error 'Undefined reference to odb::pgsql::database::database'

Tags: odb

I'm trying to use [odb](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/) for my first cpp project (based on progress database).
I have [installed](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/install-unix.xhtml) everything i need and want to connect to my database. 
I wrote a simple instance for my database connection:

```
#include <odb/database.hxx>
#include <odb/pgsql/database.hxx>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

std::unique_ptr<odb::database> db (
        new odb::pgsql::database (
                "postgres",     // database login name
                "postgres", // database password
                "test" // database name
        ));
```

and got this linking problem:

```
...: Undefined reference to `odb::pgsql::database::database(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, odb::details::transfer_ptr<odb::pgsql::connection_factory>)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think i need to extend my CMakeList.txt (still auto generated), but what i have to link ? ...

Comment: Make sure you compiled profile libraries for pgsql as described [here](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/install-unix.xhtml). Then you need to link your application against both libodb-pgsql.so and libodb.so

Comment: Thank you! I already solved my problem. I linked it totally wrong, it was my first time that i tried it manuel.

Comment: What did you do wrong and how did you solve it? I'm' having the same problem, but with SQLite and I'm clueless.